# Double hashed HashTable rehashing problem

Tags: java, hashtable, double-hashing

I need to implement a hash table with open addressing and double hashing for school project. I can add up to 56 entries, but when it tries to add 57th and rehashes it, it says that the word exist (from addWord() method) while it shouldn't.

```
for (int k = 0; k < 57; ++k) {

    word = "s" + k;

    h.addWord(word);
    System.out.println("Word = " + word + " KEY = " + h.hash(word));

    }
```

output:

```
Word = s0 KEY = 0
...
Rehashing the table!
Word = s4 KEY = 11
...
Rehashing the table!
Word = s7 KEY = 14
...
...
...
Word = s55 KEY = 45
Rehashing the table!
F28DA_CW1.WException: Word exist!
    at F28DA_CW1.HTableWords.addWord(HTableWords.java:124)
    at F28DA_CW1.HTableWords.rehash(HTableWords.java:178)
    at F28DA_CW1.HTableWords.addWord(HTableWords.java:96)
    at F28DA_CW1.test.main(test.java:17)
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test {
```

main method class(everything was breaking since main method wanted every function static)

```
public class test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test t = new test((float) 0.5);
        String word = "";

        for (int k = 0; k < 2000; ++k) {
            word = "s" + k;
            try {
                t.addWord(word);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error seems to be in tempTable[j] = hTable[i]; line (166). I cannot figure it out what is wrong with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been stuck with it for 2 days.

Edit: So the problem is now at doubleHash() method which is giving me a negative number -27 after 100 entries. Can someone please verify if the formula is right?

Comment: I'm too lazy to rewrite this into something I could actually run for myself. Can we have a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Anyway, your tableSize does not match the size of htable (one is multiplied by 2 only, the other is 2* and nextPrime), I think they should be aligned. I'm not sure it is **the** problem, it is **a** problem.

Comment: Hi. So I managed to trace the problem in the rehash() method. When there was a collision and it tried to put the value inside a double hashed index, it would keep running the loop and kept trying to insert the value into different indexes because of the loop. Simply breaking out of it after inserting fixed my problem. Now I have a new one, I'm getting arrayoutofbound exception at 100th entry. Here's a trace of my entries + revised addWord() and rehash() methods: https://pastebin.com/u58nZQAZ

Comment: I have also reduced the amount of code. Please let me know if it is short enough.

Comment: So I have found out that my doubeHash() method is giving me a negative value at 101th word, that's why I'm getting ArrayOutOfBoundsException. Can someone please look at it and tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: I'm having trouble believing that doubleHash() is returning a negative number, since `(giveCode(s) % 5)` varies between -4 and 4. 5 - (-4) = 9, 5 - 4 = 1 (Note the significance that % returns the remainder in Java, not the mathematical modulus.)

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you debug this with a MCVE, as suggested by jakub_d.

Comment: hash() might be negative, as p%q gives negative results for negative p, doubleHash being negative looks strange, yes

Comment: what's still missing for a MCVE we could run is a main method :)

Comment: Hi. I have updated the post with MCVE. Please let me know if it's still not okay.

Comment: From what I can tell, it looks like your `hash()` call in your `wordExists()` function is overflowing the integer value limit and wrapping around to a negative number, and then is being used as an array index, which causes the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now all you need to do is replace the % operations with a custom mod that will avoid the negative results. When I do that, I no longer see anything suspicious in the output.

```
public static int mod2(int p, int q) {
    int m = p%q;
    if (m<0) return m+q;
    return m;
}
```